# CakePHP 3: Link to target _blank in static pages

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have a problem with links to pdf downloads on static pages in a cakePHP 3 template. We have some static pages, which include downloads to some documents (mostly pdf, doc and xlsx files), which should be opened in a new tab - as wished by the customer :/

I tried:

```
<a href="<?= $this->Url->build(DS.'files'.DS.'myPdf.pdf); ?>" target="_BLANK">Download Me</a>
```

When I click this link in chrome a new tab will be opened with the file and the source tab will be routed to /pages/undefined. I also tried to use the new HTML5 download attribute, which won't work in Safari and IE though and also get the same problem. 
Do I have to adjust my routes.php to allow file downloads of FTP uploaded files? I have read: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files, but in my case I don't have a model for my uploads.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the files stored in webroot or outside it?

Comment: Files are stored in a subfolder in webroot.

Comment: The link in your post doesn't require a model. You can just pass in the path to the file and it should work.

Comment: Indeed I had a problem with a javascript click event, which was bound to a <li> container, which contains the actual link. Thank you anyway @chrisShick  (y)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the CSS-classes that you select via jQuery for use at another part of the website ;)